# What should I do about this regression analysis?

Tags: regression, independence, assumptions

I did regression analysis.

It's about incoming calls and amount of orders.

I got a result like this.

> summary(ireg)

Call:

lm(formula = 1/sqrt(ie) ~ ia + id)

Residuals:

```
   Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max
```

-0.0075193 -0.0019483  0.0002774  0.0018405  0.0093027

Coefficients:

```
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
```

(Intercept)  3.364e-02  4.348e-04  77.374  < 2e-16 ***

ia          -6.968e-05  1.308e-05  -5.326 1.40e-07 ***

id          -7.322e-06  1.379e-06  -5.311 1.51e-07 ***

---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘***’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.002648 on 629 degrees of freedom

Multiple R-squared:  0.08148,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.07856

F-statistic:  27.9 on 2 and 629 DF,  p-value: 2.462e-12

The model was ok. But verifying the assumption about regression analysis, 
I got a problem about independence assumption.

When I did D-W test, I got this result

> durbinWatsonTest(ireg)

lag Autocorrelation D-W Statistic p-value

1       0.5997129     0.7925516       0

Alternative hypothesis: rho != 0

Yes, it doesn't satisfy the assumption.

But the graph from the plot looks ok.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Was my interpreting wrong? what should I do?

Comment: You can't judge whether a model is 'good' based on output alone. What kind of data is this? Why are you using an inverse-square-root transformation? Also, using hypothesis testing to check multiple assumptions is bound to result in false positives. Is there reason to assume auto-correlation between these observations; Are they not independent? Lastly, your model explains 8.1% of the variance in your response variable. Is this considered good in your field?

Comment: indent all your output 4 spaces (select a block of output, click the code tool at the top of the edit window)

Comment: @FransRodenburg As I explained at the top of this question, these data is about incoming calls and amount of orders.  y is inbound calls and x is amount of orders.  The reason I used inverse-square-root transformation is I found that this model is heteroscedasticity. So I transformed y. They are independent. Cause the method getting this values are not related. So I can say it's independent. I am also guess that there is auto-corelation, but I don't think they have. Of course we can't say 8.1% of explains are good model. But I just want to get the model which doesn't have any problem.

Comment: Why not the other way around? Are you interested in how orders cause calls or visa versa? Since these are both counts, I don't think you should transform you response. Instead, you can model these counts with a Poisson or negative binomial GLM.